# Remove Decimal Pipe while downloading Table

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

In a html Table, For a certain column I am using Decimal Pipe to restrict the values to 2 Digits. However I am also Downloading that table to Excel and CSV. While Downloading I want to remove the decimal Pipe and want the values as it is. What is the approach that I should follow to remove the Pipe?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

[DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) is used to transform the data on template only for showing in certain format but it does not change the object. You should still be able to use the object without any transformation other places.
For ex, you can create a method and pass the object to it as argument and write logic to download the table in ts file.

Comment: I get it. Although while downloading I am passing the Html Table as input to Download Function. So it is downloading the table as it is with the transformed values.

Comment: Since the date attached to table is already processed through DatePipe transformation and Html is static, you won't be able to get the original value. You will have to use original object only.